# How can I configure apache to send an email on every HTTP error 500

Tags: http, apache, httpd.conf

I have some server applications running on apache2; Ruby on Rails, PHP and others.

In all cases I would like apache to send me an email whenever apache responds a HTTP error 500 Internal server error.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### It is not possible to configure apache to send emails.

There are some things you can do to achieve the same result:

1. You can use the [ErrorDocument directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) to let it point to some CGI
   script, that be a perl, PHP, or any other server-side executed
   script. The script can then send an email and respond a Error 500
   document.
2. You can use some external tool to watch your apache log
   files and configure theese tools to send you emails. There are several tools and ways to do this. For Linux many
   tools and methods are suggested on
   https://serverfault.com/questions/45246/linux-monitor-logs-and-email-alerts
3. Write an apache module. I think that mod_tee is a good starting point.

Comment: ErrorDocument catches only Apache errors, and not PHP fatal errors. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765319/apaches-errordocument-directive-does-not-redirect/5839076#5839076)

Answer (score 11):

One way you can do this is use a php script that sends email, as well as output some sort of 500 message. Then use the `ErrorDocument` directive:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /path/to/script/that/sends/email.php
```

Comment: Thanks for an excellent workaround. However the applications all have some custom pages for error 500. A typical rails application have a file public/500.html that is shown upon an internal server error. Your proposal would interfere with these application specific error documents.

Comment: @Jarl Well, something else you can try is parsing the apache log files, or write something that reads output from `tail -f`

Answer (score 4):

Create a script called `log_monitor.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $cachefile="/var/cache/lastpos-apache2-scan4maxclntOrSigKill";
my $logfile="/var/log/httpd/error_log";
my $searchstr=" 500 ";

my $lastpos=0;
if (-f $cachefile) {
    open FH,"<".$cachefile;
    $lastpos=<FH>;
    close FH;
};

my $newpos=(stat $logfile)[7];

open FH,"<".$logfile;
seek FH,$lastpos,0;
while (<FH>) {
    print if m/$searchstr/i;
};
close FH;

open FH,">".$cachefile;
print FH $newpos;
close FH;
```

modify `$searchstr` as needed. note the spaces around "500", since you don't want to match errors which contain a 404 on a file that has "500" in its path or filename (among other places).

configure the script to run every X minutes via cron. the greater the value of X, the less emails you will get (only 1 email every X minutes for all the errors that match the strings you supply). the results of the cron job will get emailed to you automatically (if cron is setup properly)

Comment: How does this script know my email ID?

Comment: @ShahAbazKhan the script uses the email address cron uses. It is not setup in the script.