# custom apache 500 error PHP page

Tags: php, apache, custom-error-pages

Alright, think I am about to loose my mind here...

Been trying and testing, but cannot seem to get a custom HTTP 500 error page to load. Chrome keeps serving me the default "This page isn't working, HTTP error 500" error page.

The steps I have taken:

- Created 500.php file, which would show the custom page I need
- Altered the .htaccess file with the lines below
- Created a file on the server that would load a non-existent class, thus causing a 500 error.
- Access_log is showing the request and the 500 status

Accesslog

> :1 - - [10/Aug/2018:20:51:39 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Errorlog

> [Fri Aug 10 20:51:39.156104 2018] [php7:error] [pid 11608] [client ::1:65263] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'tests' not found in /private/var/www/development/public_html/index.php:7\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /private/var/www/development/public_html/index.php on line 7

.htaccess lines

```
ErrorDocument 400 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 405 /405.php
ErrorDocument 408 /408.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
ErrorDocument 502 /502.php
ErrorDocument 504 /504.php
```

Apache 2.4+
PHP 7+

I am not seeing the issue here, especially since the 404 version above is working flawlessly. 500.php contains just echo '500';

Am I missing some Apache settings here? is it because it is local...

Comment: Just found this post here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765319/apaches-errordocument-directive-does-not-redirect/5839076#5839076. Seems like the 500 error never "reaches" Apache... so does this mean I need to create some sort of custom error catcher in my  framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comment is essentially correct.  Many 500 errors do will not reach apache in a way that `.htaccess` will be able to redirect to an error document.

There are 2 ways that you can put out custom templates for 5xx errors.  Which one you use will depend on exactly what the error is.  If the error is "[Catchable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php)" You simply need to wrap your function in a `try/catch` block.  Something like this:

```
try{
    someUndefinedFunction();
} catch (Throwable $exception) { //Use Throwable to catch both errors and exceptions
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error'); //Tell the browser this is a 500 error
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Note that in this example, the 500 error header had to be set manually.  This is because since the error is inside a `try{}` block the server didn't actually error out from the perspective of the browser.

If the 500 error is being caused by something that isn't catchable then you need to register a custom shutdown function.  This is less common in php7+ but still may be necessary depending on what you're doing.  The way that is done would be to include something like this:

```
function handle_fatal_error() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    if (is_array($error)) {
        $errorCode = $error['type'] ?? 0;
        $errorMsg = $error['message'] ?? '';
        $file = $error['file'] ?? '';
        $line = $error['line'] ?? null;

        if ($errorCode > 0) {
            handle_error($errorCode, $errorMessage, $file, $line);
        }
    }
}
function handle_error($code, $msg, $file, $line) {
    echo $code . ': '. $msg . 'in ' . $file . 'on line ' . $line;
}
set_error_handler("handle_error");
  register_shutdown_function('handle_fatal_error');
```

Comment: Yes, this has helped me greatly :) Although set_shutdown_function should be register_shutdown_function().
Also the ?? notation was not accepted, the idea is solid!

Comment: You're right! Fixed the code. The ?? Operator requires php7.