# Send another document’s contents in PHP

Tags: php, apache, error-handling

I’m trying to use a custom error handling system in PHP.

I want to send a certain document in place of the one that causes the error, but I don’t want to redirect.

Pretty much, I’m trying to replicate what ErrorDocument does (But I can’t use ErrorDocument, as it’s a 500 error).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792814/custom-apache-500-error-php-page

Comment: @MarkusZeller I’m looking for a way to send a specific document in place of the error causing one, not just a message. Sorry if I wasn’t clear.

Comment: If you get a 500 error, it means that the script crashed. So the script can't do anything else to send an alernate response.

Comment: It's like giving your own eulogy.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Alright, I got it.

I had to require the error showing script in my handler (registered in register_shutdown_function).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).