Custom 500 page not shown in apache docker
I am trying to use php/apache in docker and I want to have a custom 500 page. I am trying it out on localhost and it never shows the page.
Dockerfile
FROM php:7.4-apache
COPY . /var/www/html/
COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf \
    && echo "<Directory /var/www/html/>" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf \
    && echo "    AllowOverride All" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf \
    && echo "    Require all granted" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf \
    && echo "</Directory>" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

RUN a2enmod rewrite

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]

.htaccess
ErrorDocument 500 /error.html

PHP page
<?php
nonExistentFunction();
?>

Error html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Error Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Unexpected Error</h1>
</body>
</html>

Standard browser error page is shown, there is nothing in apache logs

Run as follows:
docker run --rm -p8080:80 myimage

I did try a try/catch as per this post and it made no difference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51793178/1033684

Side note: PHP 7.4 is pretty outdated and should no longer be in use anywhere

are you sure your error page has mounted to the correct place? What do the logs say?

@delboy1978uk all these files are in /var/www/html: 500.php  Dockerfile  error.html  php.ini. There is no apache log.

ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html works fine for 404s, it's just 500. Happens in PHP 8 as well.

[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

I gave up with Apache and did it at the PHP level:
error_handler.php
<?php
function handleException($exception) {
    error_log($exception); 
    http_response_code(500);
    include 'static_500.html'; 
    exit;
}

function handleError($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
}

function handleShutdown() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    if ($error && ($error['type'] & (E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR | E_COMPILE_ERROR))) {
        error_log($error['message']);
        http_response_code(500);
        include 'static_500.html'; 
    }
}

set_exception_handler('handleException');
set_error_handler('handleError');
register_shutdown_function('handleShutdown');
?>

500.php
<?php 
require 'error_handler.php';

nonExistentFunction(); 
?>

This works but it's not how I would like to do it.
